# Hibernate single table inheritance - base class nested as a property inside a subclass throws PropertyAccessException

Tags: java, hibernate, single-table-inheritance

I have the following class structure with 2 base classes (Filter and Map).

```java
@Entity
public abstract class Filter {
}
@Entity
public class AFilter extends Filter {
}
@Entity
public class BFilter extends Filter {
}

@Entity
public abstract class Map {
    public abstract Filter getFilter();
}
@Entity
public class AMap extends Map {

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private AFilter filter;

    @Override
    public AFilter getFilter() {
        return filter;
    }

    public void setFilter(AFilter filter) {
        this.filter = filter;
    }
    
}
@Entity
public class BMap extends Map {

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private BFilter filter;

    @Override
    public BFilter getFilter() {
        return filter;
    }

    public void setFilter(BFilter filter) {
        this.filter = filter;
    }

}
```

When I query the database and the resultset has an instance of an AMap, I get the following exception:

```
@Override
public List<Map> getMaps() {
    Criteria criteria = dao.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Map.class);
    return criteria.list();
}
```

> org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set field value
> [com.xxx.filter.BFilter@6197da84] value by reflection : [class
> com.xxx.map.AMap.filter] setter of com.xxx.map.AMap.filter

I tried to debug the Hibernate(v5.4.18) library a little bit, somehow it assumes Map.class's `filter` property is an instance of BFilter, rather than a dynamic subclass based on the Map subclass type.

This is the query generated by Hibernate (edited to remove extra fields and join tables):

```
select this_.id as id2_103_4_, this_.name as name15_103_4_, this_.status as status16_103_4_, this_.filter_id as filter_25_103_4_, this_.DTYPE as dtype1_103_4_, claimfilte5_.id as id2_89_3_, claimfilte5_.companyId as companyi3_89_3_, claimfilte5_.tableName as tablenam5_89_3_, claimfilte5_.zoomLevel as zoomleve6_89_3_ from public.Map this_ left outer join  public.Filter claimfilte5_ on this_.filter_id=claimfilte5_.id
```

Looking at the query, Hibernate does not select the `dtype` column for the filter table. => Causing the problem.

This is the result of the query with psql:

```
id2_103_4_ | name15_103_4_ | status16_103_4_ | filter_25_103_4_ | dtype1_103_4_ | id2_89_3_ | companyi3_89_3_ | tablenam5_89_3_ | zoomleve6_89_3_
------------+---------------+-----------------+------------------+---------------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------
  245921700 | 123123        | t               |        245921702 | BMap          | 245921702 |              16 | B               |
  250077365 | Test2         | t               |        250077367 | BMap          | 250077367 |               4 | B               |
  250365744 | Test          | t               |        250365746 | BMap          | 250365746 |               0 | B               |
  250367720 | test3         | f               |        250367722 | BMap          | 250367722 |               0 | B               |
  254371277 | gdal new test | t               |        254371279 | BMap          | 254371279 |               0 | B               |
  254371748 | test4         | t               |        254371750 | AMap          | 254371750 |               0 | A               |
(6 rows)
```

When I add the dtype column manually (to show that the dtype column is set properly on the filter table):

```
id2_103_4_ | name15_103_4_ | status16_103_4_ | filter_25_103_4_ | dtype1_103_4_ | id2_89_3_ | companyi3_89_3_ | tablenam5_89_3_ | zoomleve6_89_3_ |    dtype
------------+---------------+-----------------+------------------+---------------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------
  245921700 | 123123        | t               |        245921702 | BMap          | 245921702 |              16 | B               |                 | BFilter
  250077365 | Test1         | t               |        250077367 | BMap          | 250077367 |               4 | B               |                 | BFilter
  250365744 | Test          | t               |        250365746 | BMap          | 250365746 |               0 | B               |                 | BFilter
  250367720 | test3         | f               |        250367722 | BMap          | 250367722 |               0 | B               |                 | BFilter
  254371277 | gdal new test | t               |        254371279 | BMap          | 254371279 |               0 | B               |                 | BFilter
  254371748 | test4         | t               |        254371750 | AMap          | 254371750 |               0 | A               |                 | AFilter
(6 rows)
```

I can query the database without any problems if I create a criteria using subclasses:
`dao.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(AMap.class)`
or
`dao.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(BMap.class)`

but that's not what I want.

How can I get Hibernate to recognize the correct subclass?

Comment: do you have getters and setters for AFilter filter and BFilter filter?

Comment: Yes, I do. I have updated the question to show them.

Comment: are Map and Filter abstract classes? could you try adding also the method `public abstract void setFilter(Filter filter);` in Map

Comment: Yes, they are abstract classes (updated the question). Getting the same error even if I add the abstract setter, unfortunately.

Comment: @nilgun how do you resolve the implementation? How do you know it's the class A or B?

Comment: Also is that everything when it comes to the mapping? You don't have any other annotations?

Comment: Hibernate resolves the subclasses using the dtype column by default. I didn't change the default behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please also show the queries that are generated. I guess that your data might be messed up i.e. you have a `AMap` that refers to a `BFilter` rather than an `AFilter`. Maybe you need to force the use of discriminators by annotating `@DiscriminatorOptions(force = true)` on `Filter`.

UPDATE:

The key point is that the fields have distinct names in the subtypes. Hibernate supports implicit downcasts i.e. it would be possible to use `select m.filter from Map m` and that would resolve to the downcasted association. Since there are multiple possible downcasts that have that property, there is a conflict. I actually implemented support for this part in Hibernate, but I guess that the discriminator is simply missing in that special case.

Comment: I added the queries. You can also see the data. You were right that the problem was in the query that it does not bring the `dtype` column from the filter in the first place. Adding the `@DiscriminatorOptions(force = true)` on the `Filter` class didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Can you try to rename the fields in the `AMap` and `BMap` class to e.g. `filterA` and `filterB`?

Comment: I had tried it (renaming the `filter` field and the getters/setters in the `AMap` and `BMap` subclasses) and it works. But then I can not use the abstract Map.getFilter method.

Comment: You can just add that method in addition. The key point is that the fields have distinct names in the subtypes.

Comment: Changing the field name but keeping the getters and setters as getFilter/setFilter solved the problem. I also had to create two more columns afilter_id, bfilter_id and set them properly for each subtype. I still don't understand why the existing valid Java code would not work. Do you think it is a bug with Hibernate?

Comment: It might be a bug, but this is a pretty complex matter because Hibernate supports _implicit downcasts_ i.e. it would be possible to use `select m.filter from Map m` and that would resolve to the downcasted association. Since there are multiple possible downcasts that have that property, there is a conflict. I actually implemented support for this part in Hibernate, but I guess that the discriminator is simply missing in that special case. It would be awesome if you could submit a bug report with a reproducer!

Comment: I will submit a bug report, thank you. Can you also edit your answer with the solution so that I can accept it.